# How to split XAML Designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Can I split `XAML Designer` to one view `XAML` and one view Design？

Like this

[image]

[image]

But now can only see XAML or design. I want see both on same time in addition to the original split view， how to implement?

=========================================================================
Append：
maybe i did't describe it clear, i want is two subwindows to respectively show XAML and Desing，Plug-in can be？

Comment: two buttons in the corner `[|]` and `[-]` should show split view; also check default settings in "Tools -> Options  -> Xaml designer -> General: Default View=Split View"

Answer (score 2):

To  the right of the 'Design' and 'XAML' tabs there are buttons to toggle the split between these two views.

[image: Toggle split view of design-XAML in VS 2015]

Comment: i konw this function , but i want is two different subwindows. one XAML,one Design

Comment: i see, is it because you have multiple monitors? if so you could set the layout to two columns, drag & unpin the xaml editor as a seperate window, and increase the width so it stretches over more than than one monitor.. not sure if this is what you need.